# Add existing user as administrator

Tags: user-access

I run several wordpress sites that I created.  A friend has asked me to help admin his existing site.  So we want to add my userid as admin to his site.

However, User | Add User allows addition of a 'brand new user' with new password, email ets.  I would much prefer not to have another wordpress user account to remember.  Can I not add my existing userid as admin to my friend's site?

Comment: Is this question about a site on Wordpress_.com_?

Comment: Ah-Ah!  Now I get it.  My friends wordpress site is hosted on a different server, so it does not know about my user account on the other server!  Stupid me.  ( If you explain this in an answer, I will accept it. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress user accounts are unique to a single installation of WordPress. Even if they are hosted on the same server, there's no simple way (and, more importantly, probably no secure way) to hook them together.

WordPress accounts on WordPress *.com* can be added to other sites, but not accounts on self-hosted WordPress installations. The only "exception" to this situation is that a user account can be added to multiple sites if those sites are all part of a multisite network (which is essentially what WordPress.com is).

*Note: Using the same email account to register user accounts on multiple sites will associate each user account with a gravatar account with the same email address, but that's pretty much only useful for getting a gravatar image or using JetPack's gravatar hovercard plugin.*